# how to solve Illuminate/database syntax error on ForwardsCalls trait

Tags: php, slim

This is just happening today when I'm updating my website. Actually I didn't even touch this file but for some reason it shows error and my website can't be loaded.

Here is the problem

```
try {
        return $object->{$method}(...$parameters);
    } catch (Error | BadMethodCallException $e) { // "|" << this is the error
        $pattern = '~^Call to undefined method (?P<class>[^:]+)::(?P<method>[^\(]+)\(\)$~';

        if (! preg_match($pattern, $e->getMessage(), $matches)) {
            throw $e;
        }

        if ($matches['class'] != get_class($object) ||
            $matches['method'] != $method) {
            throw $e;
        }

        static::throwBadMethodCallException($method);
    }
```

I have tried to search about catch one of two exception but none. How can I solve this. I don't even know about trait. Thanks before

Comment: Laravel or Slim?

Comment: I use newest version of Slim

Comment: Please try to tag questions appropriately. Good Luck!

Comment: `illuminate/database` is not a part of Slim framework. What is the version of PHP you're using? What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: I'm currently using PHP 7.2.9 and the error message was `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in /vendor/illuminate/support/Traits/ForwardsCalls on line 24` . Thats what I commented on the question. I also forgot to say that when I'm using localhost, there was no error. But it occured when I upload it to my webhosting, currently it has PHP 7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [exceptions documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.catch)

> In **PHP 7.1** and later, a catch block may specify multiple exceptions
>   using the pipe (|) character.

You're developing on a machine with newer version of PHP but deploying on an older version. You really should consider using exact same version of PHP on both machines to avoid backward compatibility issues.

To solve your problem, you can choose a newer version of PHP if your hosting company offers such a feature, or downgrade the library you're using to a version compatible to the PHP version of your host. I don't recommend the second method, downgrading a package to deal with outdated dependencies is not a good idea.

Comment: I just finished read same article about multiple exceptions in one block, its implemented on 7.1. Sad but my webshoting just support til 7.0. For now, I just edit that catch and separate them so the error does not occured again. Thanks for your answer

Comment: That would be a bad choice and I can name two reasons for that: 1)It is not a good idea to edit third party libraries files, it will cause you more problems when you need to update that library. Second, this will solve **only one* of many possible backward compatibility issues that exist in the code and you're not aware of. One possible temporary solution for you is to downgrade PHP on your local and make sure every works there, then deploy it to the server. And always check the prerequisites of libraries you use, or ideally, leave that to [composer](https://getcomposer.org).

Comment: As you suggested, I downgrade `illuminate/database` to `v 5.6` which is compatible with php 7.0. `Illuminate/database` `v  5.7` only supported for 7.1+